# Run every 10 minute but start from 5

Tags: cron

I want to run my code each 10 min, I want do it with `*/10 * * * *  ceasor    sudo python  /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py` but I want it start from 5 instead of 0,
I mean want it run on `5,15,25,35,45,55` ,

I know I can do it with `5,15,25,35,45,55 * * * *  ceasor    sudo python  /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py` but I want learn how can I start from specified minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
 5/10 * * * * caesor   sudo python  /home/ceasor/Desktop/script.py
```